# i send the request to open the activity the selected images and get the result inside fragment in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

Following Image is My Fragment and Activty code

Fragment inside one button of multiple selected to press then go for Activity and View Multiple Images the after selected images take and return to my fragment class that time I not get the result of multiple selected images ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQwXD.png)

Comment: Where is your code and the "following image" ??

Comment: Please edit your question. I don't understand anything from it.

Comment: Did you see these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28496682/onactivityresult-not-call-in-the-fragment and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20038880/onactivityresult-for-fragment

Comment: I was try to getActivity().startActivityForResult() but not working

Comment: It is said that you should not use `getActivity().startActivityForResult()` in that links. Does your fragment is nested or direct child of activity?

Comment: But i was testin getActivity().startActivityForResult() does not working so i was after remove it.  I am use the Action class inside set the public class Action {
 public static final String ACTION_PICK = "luminous.ACTION_PICK";
 public static final String ACTION_MULTIPLE_PICK = "luminous.ACTION_MULTIPLE_PICK";
}  and      <activity android:name=".CustomGalleryActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="luminous.ACTION_PICK" />
                <action android:name="luminous.ACTION_MULTIPLE_PICK" />        </activity>

Comment: I am use the Action class variable Action_Multiple_Pick and that are set the activity inside <action name = "Action_Multiple_Pick" />  so how to handle that